# Wordpress + Angularjs site migration issue: dispalys $domain variable instead of actual domain/IP

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, ubuntu-18.04

I hope everyone is healthy and safe during these weird and unprecedented times.

While I have very little experience with Wordpress and none of AngularJS, I had to migrate a Wordpress site from a "dying" server. The site was previously hosted on a Bitnami WordPress Stack and the new server is a pre-made Wordpress template from the Digital Ocean Marketplace (OS: Ubuntu18.04).

Everything went well, Wordpress is set up, database is set up and everything seems to be working fine except one part: The custom template (crucial for this website) throws the following error in the browser console:

*Firefox*:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://$domain/stories-api/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

*Chrome*:

`theme.min.js:103 GET http://%24domain/stories-api/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

In the beginning I thought this had to do with CORS headers and so I went out and broke all my security morals to get it fixed. Nothing worked.

Then I noticed that the theme used AngularJS and so I went in and downloaded Node, npm, and Gulp. I run an `npm install`, run `gulp`, restarted Apache2, but it didn't solve the problem.

If anyone is curious what the /stories-api/ is, here you go:

```js
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        $directory = "../place-stories-here/";
        // $index = 0;
        $arr = array();

        // Open a directory, and read its contents
        if (is_dir($directory)){
          if ($dh = opendir($directory)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                // Fill the array
                $obj = array('src' => $file, 'extension' => pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), 'value' => true);
                if($obj['extension'] !== "" && $obj['src'] !== '.DS_Store') {
                    array_push($arr, $obj);
                };
            };
            closedir($dh);
          };
        };
        // Create JSON
        echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        echo "request unavailable";
    };
?>
```

I run a search in the code repository to find where "stories-api" is called and I found 2 files where it is used. Both in the folder of the custom theme:

- app.js
- theme.min.js

Both use AngularJS.

---

Does anyone have an idea what could possibly be causing this and point me to the right direction?

If you need more code snippets, let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, clearly $domain is not being evaluated when it is put in the string. This could be caused by a lot of things. Could you provide a snippet in which the $domain variable is used to construct the URL? The first thing that comes to mind is perhaps some kind of [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) issue or an incorrect binding type in a directive, but those are just stabs in the dark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a few days and many restarts the only thing I had to do was:

- Go to: Settings > Permalinks
- Click on Save Changes
- Click on Save Changes again

And now it works. For some reason when migrating it needed to re-create the permalinks for the site to work properly.